# Youtube links to video only don't work anymore?

Tags: wordpress, video, youtube

I used for many years in my Wordpress site links like this one

```
https://www.youtube.com/v/IV7US2rRnMg
```

to show the video in a Shadowbox overlay on the same page. So, only the video was loaded, but not the Youtube page itself.

Since a few days this doesn't seem to work anymore. The "correct" URL is still functioning (like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IV7US2rRnMg).

Youtube changed their GUI recently. So, did they change the access with it too? Or what might pose the problem? Or how can I resolve this?

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to show your youtube video within iframe?

If so then try using this https://www.youtube.com/embed/IV7US2rRnMg which is embed url to place within iframe which shows video in shadowbox overlay

Answer (score 0):

YouTube is giving embed code for each video. This should fix your issue [image]

Comment: Thanks for that. But I am not using an iFrame. I found it »easier« (actually, I don't know exactly why I did this some years ago, probably because it's a bit smoother) to use just the link to the video in combination with shadowbox, like this: `<a href="http://www.youtube.com/v/j3sW3ptDssk" rel="lightbox;width=900;height=506">`

Comment: Could you please pass your site url.? So that i can inspect how it's working and suggest you being more specific to the point

Comment: Long searches, before I then I uninstalled the old Lightbox and Shadowbox plugin that I had, and installed the "Responsive Lightbox" from dFactory. With it, in combination with changing the links from '/v/xxx' to '/watch?v=xxx' for all entries, i worked again.